# Rounded background view doesn't round inside view

Tags: ios, swift

[image: ScreenShot]

My code:

```
backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = someValue
```

Comment: What is that grey bar? is that subview inside backgroundView?

Comment: Try setting clipsToBound = true of the inner view( grey color view).

Comment: try this 
backgroundView.clipToBounds = true

Comment: @Parham Hatanian Welcome to SO. Before posting you questions, please look for existing questions asked. I am sure this issue has been asked a thousand times before. Just make a quick search for it.

Comment: tnx @Anuraj worked

Answer (score 0):

If your gray view is a subview of `backgroundView`, try to clip bounds:

`backgroundView.clipToBounds = true`